# How to use a scikit pickle model in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pickle, spark-structured-streaming

we have a pickle for a gradient boosting model and we want to use it in a udf to score streaming data using spark structured streaming.

The udf should load the pickle model, score the record and add a column to the record for the prediction.

Is this possible?